# How to make improve compilation speed in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, development-environment

How do I compile in Angular faster? Usually, my project takes 617794ms just for updating the code once. Here is my log:

[image]

This is my angular.json

```
// =========================   angular.json ========================
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "hypeProject": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {

      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/hypeProject",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
              "src/app/_content/app.less",
              "src/app/_content/modal.less"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
             "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false
            },
            "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hypeProject:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "hypeProject:build:production"
            },
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "hypeProject:build:dev"
            },
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "hypeProject:build:local",
              "port": 8200,
              "host": "localhost"
              
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hypeProject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "danaonline-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "hypeProject:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "hypeProject:serve"
            },
            "dev": {
              "devServerTarget": "hypeProject:serve"
            },
            "local": {
              "devServerTarget": "hypeProject:serve"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "hypeProject"
}
```

Comment: show your angular.json config please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your screenshot it looks like you are using `buildOptimization` which is taking too much time, add these properties to your build config in `angular.json`:

```
   "local": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": false,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": true,
          "extractCss": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "vendorChunk": false,
           "buildOptimizer": false
     }
```

Comment: I following your instruction but it seem doesn't help. Before i got 617794ms , now i got 615692ms .  But thank you for help..

Comment: if you can show your angular.json file it will help us to know where the issue is

Comment: that my angular.json . if you can solve my problem, please let me know

Comment: @LukasReinhard i have updated my answer please check now, after updating your angular.json you will need to re run ng serve command

Comment: thanks bro its much faster than before, thanks again ..

Comment: @LukasReinhard i am glad i could help